How do I cycle through the pages of a website with selenium
I'm trying to scrape this page: https://www.lavoro.gov.it/Pagine/Cerca-nel-sito?search=big+data
As you can see at the bottom of the page there are the number of pages and the icon with the arrow that i'm clicking with selenium.

Problem is, whenever I copy the Xpath of this object i get to the second page and my code start endlessly cycling between the first and the second page.
this is the block of code I'm trying to use for opening next pages:
            next_page_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class = 'page-item pager__item pager__item--next ']")
            # search_results_url = next_page_link.get_attribute("href")
            # driver.get(search_results_url)  # <--- open next page with results using URL
            next_page_link.click()   # <--- or click link 

and when the script try to go to the third page I get this error:
[DEBUG] Exception: Message: element click intercepted: Element <li class="page-item pager__item pager__item--next ">...</li> is not clickable at point (1181, 869). Other element would receive the click: <div class="popup-content info eu-cookie-compliance-content">...</div>

But I can't seem to go past the second page, someone knows how to do it?
Here's the full code for reference
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
#from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException

import time

# ---

import selenium
print('Selenium:', selenium.__version__)

# ---

def scrape_page(driver, keyword):
    try:

        
        # try:
        #     print('Clicking cookie banner')            
        #     cookie_banner = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='popup-buttons']/button[1]")
        #     cookie_banner.click()
        # except Exception as e:
        #     print('Exception:', e)

        
        elements_dt = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']")
        #elements_dd = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//dl[@class='sample-list.results']/dd/a")
        
        print('[DEBUG] len(elements_dt):', len(elements_dt))
        # Lista per memorizzare i dati estratti
        data = []

        # Clicca su ciascun elemento
        #for index, element_dt, element_dd in enumerate(zip(elements_dt, elements_dd), 1):  # you can use `enumerate(..., 1)` to start `index` with `1`
        for index, element in enumerate(elements_dt, 1):  # you can use `enumerate(..., 1)` to start `index` with `1`
            
            try:
                article_url = element.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@class="search-item-link"]').get_attribute("href")
                article_title = element.text
                
                # ... DON'T CLIK LINKS BECAUSE IT WILL REMOVE CURRENT PAGE FROM MEMPRY
                # ... AND YOU WILL LOST ACCESS TO OTHER `elements` ON CURRENT PAGE
                # ...
                # ... Get `href` and later (after loop) use `.get(href)` to access subpages. 
                
                data.append({
                    'keyword': keyword,
                    'Titolo': article_title, 
                    'URL': article_url, 
                    #'Data': article_date, 
                    #'Contenuto': article_content
                })
                
                print('[DEBUG] data:', data[-1])
                # Torna alla pagina precedente
                #driver.back()
            except Exception as e:
                print("Errore durante il clic sull'elemento:", e)
                
        # work with subpages

        # for item in data:
        #     print('[DEBUG] subpage:', item['URL'])
        #     driver.get(item['URL'])
        #     #article_date = ...
        #     #article_content = ...
        #     #item['Data'] = article_date
        #     #item['Contenuto'] = article_content
             
    except Exception as e:
        print("Errore durante lo scraping della pagina:", e)
        return None

    return data

# --- main ---

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# ---

start_url = "https://www.lavoro.gov.it/"

all_data = []

keywords = ['big data', 'data warehouse', 'data lake', 'data science', 'data mining', 'data privacy', 'open data',
            'data governance', 'data literacy', 'data', 'biometric', 'analisi biometrica',
            'machine learning', 'apprendimento automatico', 'algoritm', 'calcolo', 'punteggio', 'valutazione',
            'monitoraggi','predittiv', 'cloud', 'statistic', 'reti neurali', 'rete neurale', 'neural network',
            'apprendimento profondo', 'deep learning', 'ranking', 'classificazione', 'apprendimento supervisionato',
            'apprendimento non supervisionato', 'software', 'numeric', 'rango', 'ranghi', 'rank', "Elaborazione del linguaggio naturale",
            'natural language processing', 'NLP', 'graduazione', 'transformer', 'GPT', 'Bard', 'Copilot', 'Gemini', 'DALL-E',
            'automa', 'internet delle cose', 'intelligenza artificiale']

for word in keywords:

    print("Main Page:", start_url)

    # open main page 
    driver.get(start_url)

    # find searchbar
    #click_on_search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-button")
    #click_on_search.click()
    print('Search:', word)
    searchbar = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-input")
    # put keyword in searchbar and press ENTER
    searchbar.send_keys(word)
    searchbar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    
    time.sleep(5) # wait for results
    
    #get current url (because it could load different URL to show results)
    search_results_url = driver.current_url
    
    # start scraping results (with pagination):
    #while True:  # try to get all pages
    for _ in range(999):  # try to get only 3 pages
        print("Scraping:", search_results_url)
        
        page_data = scrape_page(driver, word)  # <--- only scraping, without `.get(url)`, I send `word` only to add it to `data`
        
        if page_data:
            all_data.extend(page_data)

        driver.get(search_results_url) # go back to result after visiting subpages - to get link to next page 
        
        try:
            next_page_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class = 'page-item pager__item pager__item--next ']")
            search_results_url = next_page_link.get_attribute("href")
            driver.get(search_results_url)  # <--- open next page with results using URL
            #next_page_link.click()   # <--- or click link 
        except Exception as e:
            print('[DEBUG] Exception:', e)
            print('[DEBUG] break')
            #input('Press ENTER to continue')
            break  # exit loop
            
driver.quit()

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)

input("Press ENTER to close")

df.to_excel('lavoro_scrape_tot.xlsx')


Remove the try-except, get the actual error message, and edit it into your question.

why click the next button when you can navigate to the page using the url? (&page=1)

Even if i use href my code is still cycling between the first two page

what do you mean? this url https://www.lavoro.gov.it/Pagine/Cerca-nel-sito?search=big%20data&page=4 will take you to the fifth page, keep count of which page you're on, and increment

I tried but It seems like It automatically goes back, I don't really know why this Is happening. How would you writer my code? I'm really scraping my head right now

are you using driver.get()? how are you navigating the next page?

Yeah, I can post the full code of you want but I'm using It, I used the same code for other websites changing only the XPaths and It worked like a charm

please post full code

Ok I just modified my original post, thank you

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Did you generate the code above with ChatGPT or another AI?

The problem is that the link you're trying to click is actually hidden behind the cookie banner. There are a few options:

Accept the cookies.
Work around the banner.

The script below accepts the cookies and navigates to the next page.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

start_url = "https://www.lavoro.gov.it/"

all_data = []

keywords = ['big data', 'data warehouse', 'data lake', 'data science', 'data mining', 'data privacy', 'open data',
            'data governance', 'data literacy', 'data', 'biometric', 'analisi biometrica',
            'machine learning', 'apprendimento automatico', 'algoritm', 'calcolo', 'punteggio', 'valutazione',
            'monitoraggi','predittiv', 'cloud', 'statistic', 'reti neurali', 'rete neurale', 'neural network',
            'apprendimento profondo', 'deep learning', 'ranking', 'classificazione', 'apprendimento supervisionato',
            'apprendimento non supervisionato', 'software', 'numeric', 'rango', 'ranghi', 'rank', "Elaborazione del linguaggio naturale",
            'natural language processing', 'NLP', 'graduazione', 'transformer', 'GPT', 'Bard', 'Copilot', 'Gemini', 'DALL-E',
            'automa', 'internet delle cose', 'intelligenza artificiale']

for word in keywords:
    driver.get(start_url)

    time.sleep(5)

    # Accept cookies.
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.agree-button").click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass

    print(f"Search: {word}.")
    searchbar = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-input")
    searchbar.send_keys(word)
    searchbar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)

        next = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[rel='next']")
        # Check if next button is disabled (no more data).
        if next.get_attribute("aria-hidden") is not None:
            print("No more data.")
            break
        next = next.get_attribute("href")
        print(f"Next page: {next}.")

        driver.get(next)
            
driver.quit()

Output should look like this:
Search: big data.                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Next page: https://www.lavoro.gov.it/Pagine/Cerca-nel-sito?search=big%20data&page=1.                                                                                                                                                    
Next page: https://www.lavoro.gov.it/Pagine/Cerca-nel-sito?search=big%20data&page=2.                                                                                                                                                    
Next page: https://www.lavoro.gov.it/Pagine/Cerca-nel-sito?search=big%20data&page=3.                                                                                                                                                    
Next page: https://www.lavoro.gov.it/Pagine/Cerca-nel-sito?search=big%20data&page=4.                                                                                                                                                    
Next page: https://www.lavoro.gov.it/Pagine/Cerca-nel-sito?search=big%20data&page=5.                                                                                                                                                    
Next page: https://www.lavoro.gov.it/Pagine/Cerca-nel-sito?search=big%20data&page=6.                                                                                                                                                    
Next page: https://www.lavoro.gov.it/Pagine/Cerca-nel-sito?search=big%20data&page=7.                                                                                                                                                    
Next page: https://www.lavoro.gov.it/Pagine/Cerca-nel-sito?search=big%20data&page=8.                                                                                                                                                    
No more data.                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Search: data warehouse.                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Next page: https://www.lavoro.gov.it/Pagine/Cerca-nel-sito?search=data%20warehouse&page=1.                                                                                                                                              
Next page: https://www.lavoro.gov.it/Pagine/Cerca-nel-sito?search=data%20warehouse&page=2.                                                                                                                                              
No more data.

